# SSIS Replace string for median

Tags: ssis

I have a column with numbers, and some string lines. I intend to replace the string by the average of numeric values​​. How can I do this?

Example:

```
1 4
2 6
3 NA
4 10
5 NA
6 10
7 5
```

line numbers = 5
average = 7

Result:

```
1 4
2 6
3 7
4 10
5 7
6 10
7 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a derived column to replace NA with null. Store the data in a staging table with both fields as int data type. Your stage will look like this. Please make sure you do not have a table named Med already existing in your database!!

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Med]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Med]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Med](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Val] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Med] ([Val])
VALUES (4), (6), (null), (10), (null), (10), (5);   


SELECT * FROM Med;

DECLARE @Average as int; ----- Choose the right data type to meet your requirement

SELECT @Average = AVG (VAL) FROM Med;

/* Replace Update with Merge to make it more efficient
Update MED
SET Val = 
CASE 
    WHEN Val IS NULL THEN @Average
    ELSE Val
END
*/

MERGE MED as TARGET
USING
(
    SELECT ID FROM MED WHERE Val IS NULL
)
AS SOURCE ON SOURCE.ID = TARGET.ID

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
    SET TARGET.Val = @Average
;

SELECT * FROM Med

ROLLBACK
```

GO